# Flutter, how to call async function (api request) under setState

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to call an async api request inside setState but when I make setState async, It does not work properly. Otherwise, I can not await for the response. My request in controller:

```
 void fetchList() async {
    isLoading(true);
    try {
      var _list = await Requests.getYesillemeList();
      if (_list != null) {
        yList.value = _list;
      }
    } finally {
      reOrderList();
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

If I call controller.fetchList() inside setState, I can not get response even it is awaiting for the response inside fetchList function. I am getting response when I make setState async, make fetchList Future of void and await for controller.fetchList inside setState but then rest of the code is not working properly. So, how can I call my api request inside setState and wait for a response.

Comment: are you using Getx?

Comment: @suzan yes I use Getx.

Comment: In that case, you do not need to use setState to update the data. Just use Getx reactive methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get), You can use GetX reactive widgets/methods

Example:

**Controller**

```
class MyClass extends GetxController{

    Rx<MyModel> yList = <MyModel>[].obs;
    RxBool isLoading = false;

      void fetchList() async {
        isLoading(true);
        try {
          var _list = await Requests.getYesillemeList();
          if (_list != null) {
            yList.value = _list;
          }
        } finally {
          reOrderList();
          isLoading(false);
        }
      }

}
```

**Widget/Page**

```
class DashboardPage extends GetView<MyClass>{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        controller.fetchList();
        return Obx(() => Text("${controller.yList.length}"));
    }
}
```